# How to access data of a table related to a module in suite crm using REST API

Tags: rest, api, sugarcrm, suitecrm

```
   $entryArgs = array(
   'session' => $sessId,
  'module_name' => 'SecurityGroups',
  'query' => "securitygroups_users.securitygroup_id = 'id`enter code 
   here`'",
  'order_by' => '',
  'offset' => 0,
   'select_fields' => array('id','name'),
    'max_results' => 10,
    'deleted' => 0 );
   $module_result = restRequest('get_entry_list',$entryArgs);
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($module_result);
   echo "</pre>";
```

I want to get the data from securitygroup_users table in suite CRM through REST API. But I am not getting anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That is middle table and you can't get any db table info using REST call in Sugar CE 6.5. You will need to write a custom REST method for that.

Comment: How to create custom method. can you show the sample code. As I have integrated the sample custom method which was shown in document of suite crm. But no idea how to get a list using custom method. I am new to suite crm. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want to write a custom Rest API  You can follow this link [Custom Rest API](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Extending_Web_Services/)

**Extending Web Services
Overview**

The guide will demonstrate how to add your own custom methods to the REST and SOAP API or extend existing ones.
Extending the API

The following example will demonstrate how to extend the v4_1 API.
Defining the Entry Point Location

This is where you define the directory that will contain your new REST and SOAP entry points. We recommend a path formatted as follows:

```
./custom/service/{version}_custom/
```

The actual location of the entry points does not matter, however, using a path such as this will allow you to call your entry points as follows:

http://{sugar_url}/custom/service/{version}_custom/rest.php
http://{sugar_url}/custom/service/{version}_custom/soap.php

**Define the SugarWebServiceImpl Class**

The next step is to define a new '`SugarWebServiceImpl`' class. Since we are using v4_1, we need to extend the file `'service/v4_1/SugarWebServiceImplv4_1.php'` and add our new method. To do this, we will create the file:

```
./custom/service/v4_1_custom/SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom.php

<?php

    if(!defined('sugarEntry'))define('sugarEntry', true);
    require_once('service/v4_1/SugarWebServiceImplv4_1.php');
    class SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom extends SugarWebServiceImplv4_1
    {
        /*
         * Returns the session id if authenticated
         *
         * @param string $session
         * @return string $session - false if invalid.
         *
         */

        function example_method($session)
        {
            $GLOBALS['log']->info('Begin: SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom->example_method');
            $error = new SoapError();

            //authenticate
            if (!self::$helperObject->checkSessionAndModuleAccess($session, 'invalid_session', '', '', '',  $error))
            {
                $GLOBALS['log']->info('End: SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom->example_method.');
                return false;
            }
            return $session;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Define the Registry Class**

Next, we will define the registry class that will register our new function. This file will be located at:

```
./custom/service/v4_1_custom/registry.php

<?php
    require_once('service/v4_1/registry.php');
    class registry_v4_1_custom extends registry_v4_1
    {
        protected function registerFunction()
        {
            parent::registerFunction();
            $this->serviceClass->registerFunction('example_method', array('session'=>'xsd:string'), array('return'=>'xsd:string'));
        }
    }
?>
```

**Define the REST Entry Point**

This REST entry point will be located at:

```
./custom/service/v4_1_custom/rest.php

<?php
    chdir('../../..');
    require_once('SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom.php');
    $webservice_path = 'service/core/SugarRestService.php';
    $webservice_class = 'SugarRestService';
    $webservice_impl_class = 'SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom';
    $registry_path = 'custom/service/v4_1_custom/registry.php';
    $registry_class = 'registry_v4_1_custom';
    $location = 'custom/service/v4_1_custom/rest.php';
    require_once('service/core/webservice.php');
?>
```

**Define the SOAP Entry Point**

This SOAP entry point will be located at:

```
./custom/service/v4_1_custom/soap.php

<?php
    chdir('../../..');
    require_once('SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom.php');
    $webservice_class = 'SugarSoapService2';
    $webservice_path = 'service/v2/SugarSoapService2.php';
    $webservice_impl_class = 'SugarWebServiceImplv4_1_custom';
    $registry_class = 'registry_v4_1_custom';
    $registry_path = 'custom/service/v4_1_custom/registry.php';
    $location = 'custom/service/v4_1_custom/soap.php';
    require_once('service/core/webservice.php');    
?>
```

**FETCH MODULE DATA USING API**
Hi I fetch module Data like this using API i have implement lot of APIS to fetch data .

You have to write this API in

```
custom\clients\base\api\filename.php

<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:", "*");


if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry)
    die('Not A Valid Entry Point');


require_once('include/SugarOAuth2/SugarOAuth2Server.php');
require_once('custom/include/api/CustomApiException.php');

class CustomApi extends ModuleApi {

    const CustomPortalAPIUser = 'b6ab0b1c-b371-0bb9-6653-570f2a0a5b47'; 

    /** @var RelateRecordApi */
    public function registerApiRest() {

        return array(

            'cRetrieve' => array(
                'reqType' => 'GET',
                'path' => array('portal', '<module>', '?'),
                'pathVars' => array('portal', 'module', 'record'),
                'method' => 'customRetrieveRecord',
                'shortHelp' => 'Returns a single record',
                'longHelp' => 'include/api/help/module_record_get_help.html',
            ),
        );
    }


    public function customAuthenticateUser($api, $args) {

        if (isset($api->request_headers['OAUTH_TOKEN'])) {
            $oauthServer = SugarOAuth2Server::getOAuth2Server();
            $oauthServer->verifyAccessToken($api->request_headers['OAUTH_TOKEN']);
            //$args_user['platform'] = $api->request_headers['OAUTH_TOKEN'];
        } else {
            //$args_user['platform'] = "base";
        }

        global $fields;

        require_once('clients/base/api/OAuth2Api.php');
        require_once('include/SugarOAuth2/SugarOAuth2Server.php');
        $args_user['platform'] = "base";
        $args_user['username'] = 'username';
        $args_user['password'] = 'password';
        $args_user['client_id'] = 'sugar';
        $args_user['grant_type'] = 'password';
        $args_user['client_secret'] = '';
        $args_user['current_language'] = 'en_us';
        $oAuth = new OAuth2Api();
        $token_data = $oAuth->token($api, $args_user);

        $admin = Administration::getSettings();

        if (isset($admin->settings['portal_defaultUser']) && !empty($admin->settings['portal_defaultUser'])) {
            $fields['assigned_user_id'] = json_decode(html_entity_decode($admin->settings['portal_defaultUser']));
        }
        return $token_data;
    }



    public function customRetrieveRecord($api, $args) {
        $is_authenticate = $this->customAuthenticateUser($api, $args);
        $result = parent::retrieveRecord($api, $args);
        if ($args['module'] == 'Module_name') {
            $result['data'] = self::data;
               your code and logic ....
        }
        return $result;
    }



}
```

Comment: I already added this code. And it is working fine. My problem is what if I want to retrieve a list of data from a module. Because here example_method is returning session only which we already have. But I want to retrieve a list using custom method. Because we have so many custom modules and table. And I am new to suite crm.

Comment: I modify my answer please chek

Comment: I am using suit 7.10 version. My folder structure is little bit varying from yours. Do i have to create the same folder as you have written in custom folder 'custom\clients\base\api\filename.php' .  can i contact you by email for further help.

Comment: Please help me with this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50265871/not-able-to-login-in-suite-crm-through-rest-api

Comment: How you are calling these functions