# Not able to login in SuiteCRM through REST API

Tags: php, rest, api, suitecrm

I am trying to login to SuiteCRM using REST API. Used the same code which was shown in demo SuiteCRM rest API document. The code is working fine on localhost. But when I am putting the file in server. It is showing a blank screen.

```
<?php

$url = "http://example.com/suitecrm/service/v4_1/rest.php";

function restRequest($method, $arguments){
 global $url;
 $curl = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $post = array(
         "method" => $method,
         "input_type" => "JSON",
         "response_type" => "JSON",
         "rest_data" => json_encode($arguments),
 );

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

 $result = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return json_decode($result,1);
}


$userAuth = array(
        'user_name' => 'username',
        'password' => md5('password'),
);
$appName = 'My SuiteCRM REST Client';
$nameValueList = array();

$args = array(
            'user_auth' => $userAuth,
            'application_name' => $appName,
            'name_value_list' => $nameValueList);

$result = restRequest('login',$args);
$sessId = $result['id'];
echo $sessId;
```

The same code is working when I am using the link of demo.suiteondemand.com and passing its username and password. 
Can it be a problem of `http` and `https`?

Comment: Are the accounts you used registered in Suite? If they are registered did they already go through the initial new user setup process?

Comment: The account is already registered. As the same code is working through localhost. It is returning me the session id as well. But when I am putting the file on server. It is returning nothing.

Comment: Were you able to login to the server suite using the credentials you used for the API?

Comment: Yes I am able to logging in.

Comment: Can you try using [this](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Application_Framework/Web_Services/Examples/REST/PHP/Logging_In/). Also, check the suitecrm.log for any problems.

Comment: do a dump of `$result` and paste it in the question.

Comment: I just tried this. Working in localhost, not working on server. Its not showing any error, showing only white screen. How to check suite crm log as I am new to suite

Comment: do `var_dump($result)` after `$result`. suitecrm.log is found on the root directory should be `www.yoursuite.com/suitecrm.log`

Comment: It is returning null in var dump on server

Comment: There is nothing in suite log file related to login error

Comment: try changing from http to https or vice versa. Also, try to change that user to admin just in case. My experience with this error is that the user account used for the API hasn't gone through the suitecrm welcome process. But since you've mentioned that you were able to login using that account you can scratch that problem. But I would suggest using the full code for the API found in the link I gave you since yours is a shorter version and it would be best to cover all grounds.